# Poor performance in OR statement MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with the following structure:

Table `counts`.

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| bin1  | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| bin2  | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| count | float(6,2)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table `coordinates`.

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| bin   | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| chr   | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| start | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| end   | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

First, I want to get all `coordinates.bin` that matches my conditions using:

```
describe select bin from coordinates where chr="chr1" AND (start between 1 AND 1000000000 OR end between 1 AND 1000000000);
+------+-------------+-------------+------+-----------------------------------+-------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys                     | key   | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-------------+------+-----------------------------------+-------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | coordinates | ref  | chr,chr_2,chr_3,start,start_2,end | chr_2 | 22      | const | 4929 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+-------------+------+-----------------------------------+-------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
```

and it works fine. Then I want, with the `coordinates.bin`, filter table counts by mapping `counts.bin1` and `counts.bin2`. I tried different queries without success:

```
describe select * from counts inner join (select bin from coordinates where chr="chr1" AND (start between 1 AND 1000000000 OR end between 1 AND 1000000000)) as subquery on bin=bin1 or bin=bin2;
+------+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------------------------------+-------+---------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys                             | key   | key_len | ref   | rows     | Extra                                          |
+------+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------------------------------+-------+---------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | coordinates | ref  | PRIMARY,chr,chr_2,chr_3,start,start_2,end | chr_2 | 22      | const |     4929 | Using where; Using index                       |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | counts      | ALL  | bin1,bin2                                 | NULL  | NULL    | NULL  | 30763816 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x6) |
+------+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------------------------------+-------+---------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------------+

describe select * from coordinates inner join counts on (counts.bin1=coordinates.bin or counts.bin2=coordinates.bin) where coordinates.chr="chr1" AND (coordinates.start between 1 AND 1000000000 OR coordinates.end between 1 AND 1000000000);
+------+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------------------------------+-------+---------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys                             | key   | key_len | ref   | rows     | Extra                                          |
+------+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------------------------------+-------+---------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | coordinates | ref  | PRIMARY,chr,chr_2,chr_3,start,start_2,end | chr_2 | 22      | const |     4929 | Using where; Using index                       |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | counts      | ALL  | bin1,bin2                                 | NULL  | NULL    | NULL  | 30763816 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x6) |
+------+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------------------------------+-------+---------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
```

but they are really slow. No key is used.

Comment: Do you have indexes on `start` and `end` on `coordinates`? How are those defined?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari, they have been indexed as `B-trees`.

Comment: I didn't ask what types are those, but how they are defined, as field combination ... can you show us the `CREATE TABLE` statements for those tables?

Comment: well, @MatteoTassinari, I used `alter table coordinates add index using btree (start);` and `alter table coordinates add index using btree (end);`